# What version number to fix an old version?

Tags: version

I'm working on a Django project and I'm being asked the following question.
For exemple :
I'm creating version 1.1.0 for a new feature.
After, I create version 1.2.0 for a second new feature.
If I must created a new version for a fix about the 1.1.0 version.
What will be the number of this version ? 1.2.1 ?
1.1.1 makes more sense. But the version order will not be correct !
What is good practice ?

Comment: There is really no clearcut answer to this as opinions differ.   Do whatever you feel is natural for your project.

Answer (score 0):

There are no good or bad practices, only "common sense" and logic.

In your case, if you have

> fix about the 1.1.0 version

*without changes* incorporated in 1.2.0 when it will be 1.1.x in release

and *when you forward-port* from 1.1.* into 1.2.0, you'll get 1.2.x

Dates of releases are irrelevant (while you follow semver), because more than 1 supported version post-releases for full line of product is natural practice.